# Incorrect results in ground state evaluation via Qiskit Nature when using Qiskit Aer Estimator

Tags: chemistry, qiskit

I am using the Qiskit Aer estimator in order to evaluate the ground state of molecules via qiskit nature on local simulators using vqe, with and without noise model. My results are completely off.
To illustrate the problem, let me add here the corresponding code snippet

```
from qiskit_nature.units import DistanceUnit
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver

driver = PySCFDriver(atom="H 0 0 0; H 0 0 0.735", basis="sto-3g")

es_problem = driver.run()

from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import JordanWignerMapper, QubitConverter

converter = QubitConverter(JordanWignerMapper())

from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SLSQP
from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms import VQEUCCFactory
from qiskit_nature.second_q.circuit.library import UCCSD
from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms import GroundStateEigensolver
```

If I take the standard Estimator from qiskit everything goes as expected

```
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator

vqe_solver = VQEUCCFactory(Estimator(), UCCSD(), SLSQP())
calc = GroundStateEigensolver(converter, vqe_solver)
res = calc.solve(es_problem)
print(res)
```

And here is the result I get

```
=== GROUND STATE ENERGY ===
 
* Electronic ground state energy (Hartree): -1.857275030145
  - computed part:      -1.857275030145
~ Nuclear repulsion energy (Hartree): 0.719968994449
> Total ground state energy (Hartree): -1.137306035696
 
=== MEASURED OBSERVABLES ===
 
  0:  # Particles: 2.000 S: 0.000 S^2: 0.000 M: 0.000
 
=== DIPOLE MOMENTS ===
 
~ Nuclear dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  1.3889487]
 
  0: 
  * Electronic dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  1.38894893]
    - computed part:      [0.0  0.0  1.38894893]
  > Dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  -0.00000023]  Total: 0.00000023
                 (debye): [0.0  0.0  -0.00000058]  Total: 0.00000058
```

If I use the Aer estimator for a noiseless simulation

```
from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as AerEstimator
seed=170

noiseless_estimator = AerEstimator(
    run_options={"seed": seed, "shots": 1024},
    transpile_options={"seed_transpiler": seed},
)

vqe_solver2=VQEUCCFactory(noiseless_estimator, UCCSD(), SLSQP())
calc2 = GroundStateEigensolver(converter, vqe_solver2)
res2 =calc2.solve(es_problem)
print(res2)
```

These are the output numbers I get. They are really different.

```
=== GROUND STATE ENERGY ===
 
* Electronic ground state energy (Hartree): -0.761369413072
  - computed part:      -0.761369413072
~ Nuclear repulsion energy (Hartree): 0.719968994449
> Total ground state energy (Hartree): -0.041400418623
 
=== MEASURED OBSERVABLES ===
 
  0:  # Particles: 2.006 S: 0.446 S^2: 0.645 M: 0.009
 
=== DIPOLE MOMENTS ===
 
~ Nuclear dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  1.3889487]
 
  0: 
  * Electronic dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  1.38395701]
    - computed part:      [0.0  0.0  1.38395701]
  > Dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  0.00499169]  Total: 0.00499169
                 (debye): [0.0  0.0  0.0126876]  Total: 0.0126876
```

I tried to use qiskit aer Estimator primitives in different environments and setups and on the IBM Quantum Lab as well to be reasonably sure that the problem does not depend from the installation.  The output I get is the same.

I expect that without noise qiskit aer Estimator provides the same results as the default Estimator, and if there are differences in the Total ground state energy value, they are below 0.01 Hartree.

How can I fix this? Am I doing anything wrong in Aer Estimator usage?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computations done above, using the two different Estimators, are not the same and this, and the optimizer choice is causing the difference.

The Estimator from qiskit.primitives, when created by default, as you do i.e Estimator(), computes an ideal outcome (statevector and matrix computation).

The Aer Estimator, you have even set it up to do sampling (though this is its default) and this will have sampling noise in the outcome. With 1024 shots the outcome is sampled 1024 timesand will be different from the ideal (ideal you can think of as an infinite number of shots). To make this the equivalent of qiskit.primitives, as per the [Aer Estimator api ref.](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.primitives.Estimator.html) set `shots=None` and `approximation=True`. You should then see the same result.

> shots (None or int) – The number of shots. If None and approximation is True, it calculates the exact expectation values. Otherwise, it calculates expectation values with sampling.

Now you can set the qiskit.primitives Estimator to sample by setting shots (`options={shots=1024}` note Aer uses run_options so again a bit different). This will cause sampling noise in its outcome. SLSQP is a classical gradient based optimizer and sampling noise can adversely affect its ability to compute a gradient, which is done, by default, with finite diff, which uses very small delta diffs around the current point to determine the slope and such noise can easily affect this. In the presence of noise SPSA as an optimizer would be a reasonable choice - it was designed to work under noise. Yes you do not have actual noise as you I believe thinking of it in Aer, i.e. a noise model say from a real device, but sampling from the ideal outcome with shots already introduces a form of noise - sampling/shot noise - which as you can see causes difficulties already.

---

I updated this answer as per my comment below, on Aer Estimator, to show the outcome when so configured

```
from qiskit_nature.units import DistanceUnit
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver

driver = PySCFDriver(atom="H 0 0 0; H 0 0 0.735", basis="sto-3g")

es_problem = driver.run()

from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import JordanWignerMapper, QubitConverter

converter = QubitConverter(JordanWignerMapper())

from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SLSQP
from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms import VQEUCCFactory
from qiskit_nature.second_q.circuit.library import UCCSD
from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms import GroundStateEigensolver

from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as AerEstimator
seed=170

noiseless_estimator = AerEstimator(
    run_options={"shots": None},
    approximation=True,
)

vqe_solver2=VQEUCCFactory(noiseless_estimator, UCCSD(), SLSQP())
calc2 = GroundStateEigensolver(converter, vqe_solver2)
res2 =calc2.solve(es_problem)
print(res2)
```

produces

```
=== GROUND STATE ENERGY ===
 
* Electronic ground state energy (Hartree): -1.857275030145
  - computed part:      -1.857275030145
~ Nuclear repulsion energy (Hartree): 0.719968994449
> Total ground state energy (Hartree): -1.137306035696
 
=== MEASURED OBSERVABLES ===
 
  0:  # Particles: 2.000 S: 0.000 S^2: 0.000 M: 0.000
 
=== DIPOLE MOMENTS ===
 
~ Nuclear dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  1.3889487]
 
  0: 
  * Electronic dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  1.388948372236]
    - computed part:      [0.0  0.0  1.388948372236]
  > Dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  0.000000327764]  Total: 0.000000327764
                 (debye): [0.0  0.0  0.000000833093]  Total: 0.000000833093
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification,, Unfortunately, setting in the Aer Estimator run_options "shots": None, "approximation":True  does not solve the big issue. The numbers are slightly changed,

I get  
Total ground state energy (Hartree): -0.041400418623 
thatis really far from the result of the Qiskit Estimator 
Total ground state energy (Hartree): -1.137306035696

Setting the optimizer to SPSA slightly improves the results, but there is still a huge difference
Total ground state energy (Hartree): -0.152248036808

Comment: `approximation` is a parameter, its not part of run options. 

`aer_estimator = AerEstimator(run_options={"shots": None}, approximation=True)`

Comment: I updated my answer to include your code with the Aer Estimator configured like that to show the outcome is the same.

Comment: You are right. With this settings the outcome is the same. Thank you very much @SteveWood.